# How to query the Stack Exchange API using an OR operator?

Tags: support, api, search

I want to query Stack Exchange by title including optional keywords (one of).

How can I query by OR operator?

For example:

```
/search/advanced?page=1&tagged=java&q=title:http OR class&order=desc&sort=votes&site=stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 3):

The API currently does not support this, but then **neither does the website itself**.

The ["How do I search?" help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) says:

> OR operator
>
> To combine results from multiple tags, separate the **tag names** (enclosed in square brackets) with the word "or": `[widgets] or [geegaws]` returns questions **tagged** with either **tag**.

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

Note that it only refers to tags in conjunction with the `or` operator.  No facility is made for general `or` operation.

Here's [a **related feature request which you can/should upvote**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158815/please-allow-using-nested-expressions-when-filtering-with-tags).

---

**Example on the main site**:

1. [Searching for `[winzip] title:folder make`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwinzip%5D%20title%3Afolder%20make) gives 3 results (currently).
2. [Searching for `[winzip] title:folder automate`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwinzip%5D%20title%3Afolder%20automate)  gives 1 result
3. [Searching for `[winzip] title:folder make or automate`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwinzip%5D%20title%3Afolder%20make%20or%20automate) **gives no results, when it *should* give at least 3 (fail)**.
4. [`[winzip] title:folder (make or automate)`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwinzip%5D%20title%3Afolder%20%28make%20or%20automate%29), etc., also fail.

The **API equivalents** ([one](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=title%3Afolder%20make&tagged=winzip&filter=!C(o*Un*wUzi0Ii8GQ&site=stackoverflow&run=true), [two](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=title%3Afolder%20automate&tagged=winzip&filter=!C(o*Un*wUzi0Ii8GQ&site=stackoverflow&run=true), [three](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=title%3Afolder%20make%20or%20automate&tagged=winzip&filter=!C(o*Un*wUzi0Ii8GQ&site=stackoverflow&run=true)) **give the same results**.

---

#### Workarounds:

The **Most timely/accurate** workaround is: for each of the optional terms, **search separately and then combine the results** (stripping duplicate matches).

For example:

1. Suppose your keywords were: `class` and `foo`.
2. [Search for `[java] title:http class`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=title%3Ahttp%20class&tagged=java&filter=!C(o*Un*wUzi0Ii8GQ&site=stackoverflow&run=true) (only 3303 results, currently).
3. [Search for `[java] title:http foo`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=title%3Ahttp%20foo&tagged=java&filter=!C(o*Un*wUzi0Ii8GQ&site=stackoverflow&run=true) (81 results).
4. Repeat for each additional keyword.
5. So we have 3384 gross results, then remove any duplicate `question_id`s for the final (net) results

This is annoying and inefficient, but it works and is easy to automate.

Other possible workarounds include using a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) query, or using a Google search with the `site:` parameter.